Flutter ListView.builder() vs List.map(): Performance difference?
I am coding a habit tracker app currently. To display all habits, I used to do it with the List.map() method:
Column(
  children: [todayList.map((habit) => HabitCard(habit: habit))],
             ...,
            ])

I used this, because I could have multiple lists fully build out on top of each other, without any UI Exceptions.
But soon I noticed a big problem: The build method was called around 10 times per Second, for only 3 habits. This of course is not acceptable, performance wise.
When I tried it with ListView.builder(), the habits only performed the build method, when actually something changed, like updating, editing, etc.
My 2 Questions:

Do you think this performance difference matters that much, considering nowdays devices are much more advanced?
How do I achieve the same effect with ListView.builder, that I did with List.map()?

See picture below of how it should look:


"How do I achieve the same effect with ListView.builder, that I did with List.map()?"  and it's not clear what that is.  You seem to have ListView.builder working already.  Can you clarify your question so we can take a stab at answering it?

in short, yes! Performance difference can be seen in the both the cases. Guide to use ListView.builder

ListView.builder might help you as it will render only the visible items.
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todayList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final habit = todayList[index];
    return HabitCard(habit: habit);
  },
)

https://www.dhiwise.com/post/flutter-listview-builder-enhancing-performance
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/boost-flutter-app-performance-lazy-loading-using-muhammad-bilal-ab3tf/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070934/11217742


Do you think this performance difference matters that much, considering nowdays devices are much more advanced?

Depends on how complex the item is, let's say there are 100 items, every item is playing a video, if you use Column to display then the memory usage is massive, because every item will be rendered at same time.

How do I achieve the same effect with ListView.builder, that I did with List.map()?

You can display item lazily, the Column always display three items, when it scrolls to end, add a new item and remove oldest item, but just use ListView.builder() please, it's easier.
